# error - illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to run this block of code but when I run the code, it shows error - illegal operation on empty resultset.

```
Connection conn =null;
Statement st =null;
ResultSet rs =null;
String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smartmall?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
String unam="root";
String pass="MARtena123@";

try{
    conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url, unam, pass);
    st =conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("select ssn from customer where ssn='"+ssntex.getText()+"'");
    rs.next();
    String strng =rs.getString("ssn");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"query executed");
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your query returned no row. Use `if (rs.next()) …`.

Comment: Have you verified that the underlying SQL returns rows?

Comment: — and then learn about SQL injection, `?` placeholders and bind variables…

Comment: i run the code many times and it was return value